# Clone Opportunity using Quick Action

Tags: opportunity, quickaction, clone

I'm trying to create a quick action button to allow reps to clone an opportunity. I noticed when I try to create this I can't select opportunity as the target object. Is this possible without code?

Answer (score 2):

[Object-specific quick actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm&type=0) need to have a relationship field between the **source object** (object you're adding the button to) and the **target object** you're creating.

For example, on an Account you might want to quickly create an Opportunity that is related to the Account. This is possible with a quick action as the Opportunity has a relationship to Account that it utilizes.

In your scenario, it sounds like you don't have a relationship field on Opportunity to itself (ex. Related_Opportunity__c). Without that, you can't actually create a quick action to create opportunity records from an opportunity. You might not want a quick action, anyway, if you don't have a need to relate the created record to the original record.

There's other options

1. The standard clone button you can drag onto the layout. Might want to test how it [functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322210&type=1&mode=1) to meet your need.
2. Screen flow or auto-launch flow through a custom button if you know what you're going to copy. This is still admin-friendly even though it's not a quick action.